# Extracting data from log file

Tags: java, regex, file-handling

I'm having a log file that contains the following code... i want to use the log file as input and filter UserName, date and count the no. of times Client disconnection, client connection and Packet drops FOR EVERY USERNAME........ 
Log Sample:

```
[ComputerC7] UserName:ABC1  id:02 | (11/22/2016 01:20:03) | Client connected.  

[ComputerC8] UserName:ABC2  id:01 | (11/24/2016 03:10:35) | Client disconnected. 

[ComputerC9] UserName:ABC5  id:04 | (11/25/2016 01:20:35) | Packet drop. 

[ComputerC7] UserName:ABC1  id:02 | (11/22/2016 01:20:03) | Packet drop.
```

I need to have unique list users. and show Connected, Disconneced, Packet Drop count for each day separately. This mayneed Some java code and regex for sure.

Output :

```
UserName: ABC1 Date:11/22/2016 Connected :1 Disconnected :0 Packet Drop:1
UserName: ABC2 Date:11/24/2016 Connected :0 Disconnected :1 Packet Drop:0
UserName: ABC5 Date:11/25/2016 Connected :0 Disconnected :0 Packet Drop:1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

Please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete answer for your first question in SO. Please make sure that you show what you have tried in the future post.

This is the regex that you need to try:

```
"UserName:([^\\s]*)(?:[^\\(]*)\\(([^\\s]*)[^\\|]*\\|\\s*([^\\.]*)"
```

And to obtain the result as you desired you can try the following approach.

```
package rejex;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *
 * @author Maverick
 */
public class Starter {

    public static HashMap<String, props> resultMap;
    public static final String regex = "UserName:([^\\s]*)(?:[^\\(]*)\\(([^\\s]*)[^\\|]*\\|\\s*([^\\.]*)";
    public static final String string = "[ComputerC7] UserName:ABC1 id:02 | (11/22/2016 01:20:03) | Client connected.\n\n"
            + "[ComputerC8] UserName:ABC2 id:01 | (11/24/2016 03:10:35) | Client disconnected.\n\n"
            + "[ComputerC9] UserName:ABC5 id:04 | (11/25/2016 01:20:35) | Packet drop.\n\n"
            + "[ComputerC7] UserName:ABC1 id:02 | (11/22/2016 01:20:03) | Packet drop.\n\n";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Starter starter = new Starter();
        starter.process();

        for (String key : resultMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.print(key);
            System.out.print(" Connected :" + resultMap.get(key).clientConnected);
            System.out.print(" Disconnected :" + resultMap.get(key).clientDisconnected);
            System.out.println(" Packet Drop :" + resultMap.get(key).packetDrop);
        }
    }

    public void process() {
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        String key = "";
        resultMap = new HashMap<String, props>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            key = "UserName: " + matcher.group(1) + " Date:" + matcher.group(2);
            if (resultMap.containsKey(key)) {
                resultMap.put(key, resultMap.get(key).increment(matcher.group(3)));
            } else {
                resultMap.put(key, new props().increment(matcher.group(3)));
            }

        }
    }

    public class props {

        int clientDisconnected;
        int clientConnected;
        int packetDrop;

        public props increment(String val) {
            if (val.contains("disconnected")) {
                clientDisconnected += 1;
            } else if (val.contains("connected")) {
                clientConnected += 1;
            } else if (val.contains("drop")) {
                packetDrop += 1;
            }

            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on the size of logs OP deals with, int might not be the best type for the counters. Also for full completeness add a File reader to your Starter class.

Comment: I agree with you. Can't we just keep it as TODO for the questioner :D ?